Definability of acyclic graphs
I think you should be able to encode the axioms of a directed, acyclic graph by introducing a strict partial order. Say E(a, b) represents there is an edge from a to b. We introduce a strict partial order $R(\cdot, \cdot)$ and axiomatize acyclicality:
\begin{align*}
    \forall a, b~E(a, b) \rightarrow R(a, b) \hspace{2cm} &\text{(A1)} \\
    \forall a, b, c~R(a, b) \land R(b, c) \rightarrow R(a, c) \hspace{2cm} &\text{(A2)} \\
    \forall a~\neg R(a, a) \hspace{2cm} &\text{(A3)}
\end{align*}
However, it seems like you can prove via compactness argument that acyclic graphs are not axiomatizable (like they did here). Which of these is correct?

You have not axiomatized the class of directed acyclic graphs. You have axiomatized the class of directed acyclic graphs equipped with a strict partial order extending the edge relation. These are different classes because they have different languages: A directed acyclic graph is an $L$-structure, where $L = \{E\}$, while your class consists of $L'$-structures, where $L' = \{E,R\}$.
In general, a class $\mathcal{K}$ of $L$-structures is basic elementary if it is the class of models of an $L$-sentence $\varphi$: $\mathcal{K} = \{M\mid M\models \varphi\}$.
A class $\mathcal{K}$ of $L$-structures is basic pseudo-elementary if there is a language $L'$ extending $L$ and an $L'$-sentence $\varphi$ such that $\mathcal{K}$ is the class of $L$-reducts of models of $\varphi$: $\mathcal{K} = \{M{\restriction} L\mid M\models \varphi\}$.
The class of directed acyclic graphs is not basic elementary, but your argument shows that it is basic pseudo-elementary.

But if you looked at the $L'$ structure, wouldn't the compactness argument still work in this case. But this would lead to a contradiction?

@AmarShah No, it wouldn't. The structures used in the compactness argument are long cycles, which cannot be expanded by a relation $R$ satisfying your axioms.

I am a little confused. Say you have a language $L' = {E, R}$. Then define the functions $\phi_3, \phi_4, \phi_5, \ldots$ where each of these represents the fact that there cannot be a cycle of length $\leq 3$, 4, 5, etc. Let $\psi$ be my axiomitization of no cycles. By the other mathexchange post $\bigwedge \phi_i \implies \psi $. Then apply compactness and completeness and we get $\phi_n \implies \psi$ for some $n$. But this is a contradiction. I have not used anything specific about $R$ except the fact that it axiomatized that there were non cycles. What is wrong with this?

@AmarShah But $\bigwedge\varphi_i$ does not entail $\psi$. A model of $\bigwedge\varphi_i$ is an acyclic directed graph with $R$ interpreted arbitrarily (for example, as the empty relation).

This makes, thank you Alex!
